Instead of radio button getting [ ] in @react-pdf-viewer
I'd uploaded a PDF having checked radio button, Instead of the radio button getting [ ] in the PDF
Please find the attachment.
Here is issue screenshot
react-pdf-viewer-radio-button-issue
Here is sample PDF for checked radio button
filled-out.pdf
Do you have a clue how to resolve my problem?
Thanks
PDF having checked radio button, Instead of the radio button getting [ ] in the PDF
I expect a checked radio button like below screenshot:
expected radio button
